# Memory Management in Java: Do I need to clean up this object after use?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have some Java code set up as follows

```
public void captureEvent(EventTrigger event) {
    // Every few minutes or so, receive and parse an event from the upstream system
    actOnEvent(event);
}

private void processEvent(EventTrigger event) {
    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
    dataObject.enrichFromEvent(event);
    performSomeActivityBasedOn(dataObject);
}
```

In this case, each time I receive an event to process, I will create a new DataObject scoped within a processing function.

Will these objects build up in memory over time, essentially causing a "memory leak," or will Java automatically clean them up?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Java's GC automatically cleans up anything objects that are not refereced. If your code saves a reference to the `DataObject` somewhere, it won't be cleaned up.

Comment: No, but why the `DataObject`? Why not just pass the event?

Comment: Why show the `captureEvent` method if it has nothing to do with your Question?

Comment: In most cases, you don't need to worry about memory leak. In your case, if you add all the dataObjects created to an array (list, set, map, etc) and that array can be referenced all the time, then these dataObjects are marked as active and won't be cleaned by GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will these objects build up in memory over time, essentially causing a "memory leak," or will Java automatically clean them up?

We have no way to tell, you have not explained what `performSomeActivityBasedOn` does with the passed `DataObject` object.

- If that method lets the object reference go out of scope, each passed `DataObject` object will become a candidate for eventual garbage collection.
- If the method retains the reference, say adding each received reference to some collection maintained over time, then yes, all the collected objects will consume more and more memory as more objects pile up.